# set Cisco Pix back to default settings

Tags: cisco, cisco-pix, reset

Trying to wipe my Cisco pix back to factory default. i login to the pix as an admin then type "configure factory-default" this doesn't work though

Comment: What do you mean "this doesn't work"?? Error code? Are you in config mode when you enter this?

Comment: when i type configure factory-default. i get this as an answer
Usage:  configure terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not in configure mode. Type `conf t` then `conf factory-default`.

Comment: Thanks Chris so for future i need to be in config mode before excuting a command. I am trying to teach myself about cisco pix etc.

Comment: There's 3 modes to any (modern) Cisco router: unprivileged, enable, and config. Each has it's own set of valid comments. Newer firmware blur the lines a bit that each "higher" level retains the commands on the previous level(s). When you're changing settings it's almost always going to be in "config" mode, which you get into by entering "conf t" in enable mode. One of the most important commands you'll find is "write" (or just "wr" for short) which is an Enable mode command. When you change settings they are not automatically saved, you have to save the running configuration by writing it.